# In systemd, how can I create a dependency with a service that takes an argument?

Tags: systemd

I have a `Type=notify` service A that needs to initialize before service B starts.  And when service A goes down, service B needs to follow suit.  The problem is service A's name isn't clearly defined.  It is `service.A@.service`.

This is my service unit B

```
[Unit]
Description=start and shutdown with Service A
BindsTo=service.A@.service
After=service.A@.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myprogram --start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/myprogam --stop
```

An example of service A invocation would be..

```
sudo systemctl start service.A@myarg.service
```

But `myarg` could be anything really so I'm confused how I'd get a handle of service A in service B.

Edit:  I'm editing `Requires` to `BindsTo` as that is the intended function.

It still isn't working.  In `sudo systemctl status service.B`

> service.B.service:3: Failed to add dependency on
> openvpn-client@service, ignoring: Unknown error -22

Edit:  Partial solution.

Instead of referencing the template service (service.A) from service.B, I can reference service.B from the template service to create the desired dependency.

So service.A unit..

```
[Unit]
Before=service.B
Requires=service.B

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/some.program
```

So, service.A requires service.B and should be started before service.B.  **This is partially working, however, service B is not shutting down when service A is shutdown.**

Comment: might it be possible to merge the services into one and run `A`'s exec part as `ExecStartPre`?

Comment: BTW: your description of the services rather asks for `BindsTo` instead of `Requires`.

Comment: Doesn't the unit in the question work for you? It should add the dependency for all instances of the template service

Comment: So do you want to start service A with a specific argument? You wrote "But `myarg` could be anything really", so I'm not sure if you yourself don't know what the argument is, or if you just mean you could chose whatever argument you'd like, and you have a specific argument to use.

Comment: @muru But only if `B` is used for also staring `A`, right? Not if `A` starts on its own.

Comment: @FelixJN for that your suggestion of `BindsTo`  would apply, but my point is more about the OP's concern about A being a template service. The syntax in the question should work fine for templates, OP shouldn't have to worry about matching specific instances of the template

Comment: So my syntax for the template service is correct?  I'll try `BindsTo` and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @aviro, myarg can be anything.  Like imagine 1 of 3 chosen randomly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding about how **systemd** works. Your line `Requires=service.A@.service` in **service.B.service** is wrongly used. Remove that line from **service.B.service** and add a dependency in **service.A@.service** like `Requires=service.B.service`.

Start carefully reading the systemD documentation, I suggest to start here:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

For you the most interesting part will start at **[Unit] Section Options**. Read carefully!

> Requires=
>
> ...
>
> **If this unit gets activated, the units listed will be
> activated as well.** If one of the other units fails to activate, and an
> ordering dependency After= on the failing unit is set, this unit will
> not be started. Besides, with or without specifying After=, this unit
> will be stopped (or restarted) if one of the other units is explicitly
> stopped (or restarted).
>
> ...

Comment: This was helpful but doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of referencing the template service (`service.A@.service`) from `service.B`, I can reference `service.B` from the template service to create the desired dependency.

So `service.A@.service` unit..

```
[Unit]
Before=service.B
Requires=service.B

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/some.program
ExecStop=systemctl stop service.B
```

So, `service.A@.service` requires `service.B` and should be started before `service.B`. Also, the `ExecStop` stops `service.B` before `service.A@.service`.

I'm not entirely happy with this solution.  The ExecStop seems hacky, and I'd rather create the dependency in `service.B` because it is mine, while `service A@.service` is not and my changes could be updated out.  I also haven't learned how to reference a template service for a dependency.

Edit: Because `service.A@.service` is not mine, my changes could be updated out.  So a better way is to use a systemd override.

```
sudo systemctl edit service.A@.service

[Unit]
Requires=service.B.service
Before=service.B.service

[Service]
# From docs, I think, options with lists need to be reset first
ExecStop=
ExecStop=systemctl stop service.B.service
```